# Problem passing variable values in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, fasm

I am trying to pass on the value of the variable "tamy" to "tam" but it doesn't work, the assembler returns "***Error: Operand Sizes do not match***"

```
org 100h

mov [tamy], 14
mov bl, [tamy]
mov [tam], bl


tam rw 1
tamy rw 1
```

I am using FASM, what am I doing wrong on this?

Comment: You declared it as a "variable" (label and `rw` together on one line, not separated by spaces), so `[tamy]` implies an operand-size of 16-bit because of `rw`.  `bl` is of course an 8-bit register.

Comment: That was the first thing I thought, and it still returns an error when using the `"eax"`register

Comment: @AndrejHatzi `eax` is a 32 bit register, not a 16 bit register.  Of course it's not going to work.  Try `ax`.  Note also that you should never say “returns an error.”  Instead, state what exact error is given!

Comment: EAX is 32 bits wide, so yes that's to be expected.  AX is the low 16 of that.  AH:AL are the 8-bit halves of AX.

Comment: I mistyped "an" for "the", the error returning was the same "Error: Operand Sizes do not match" I will try with ax now.

Comment: It is working now!! Thanks a lot, but I have yet another question how can I identity a variable operand size?